# how to turn on the boards hub in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have seen the boards hub in several videos on how to use VSTS.  It is a preview feature and shows up right between "Work Items" and "Back Logs".
I have opted in on all the preview feature but cannot get it to show up.

here is a spot in a video talking about it:
https://youtu.be/16gOTI_OBw8?t=141

Here is what my opt in features shows:
[image: opt in picture]

What am I missing??

Comment: Is one of the Preview Features you opted in to called "Board Hub"? If not, then you don't yet have the ability to opt in to that preview feature.

Comment: it is not.  I was not aware that some people have different feature options?  If that is the case then MS should stop putting videos out with options that are not available to be opted in for everybody.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood you. You thought you were asking about dashbords. Now I saw your video. I haven't this feature as well. I searched for it on the marketplace and nothing. Apparently it is not deployed to all users so far. I also deleted my answer, since I pointed you to the wrong direction. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem -- thanks for the effort!

Comment: The feature is probably in "private preview" which considering the content of the video in which it is seen would be ironic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available for now. And it will be available in the near future.

Details, you can find in [Features under development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/#features-under-development):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that link -- that is very helpful and worth bookmarking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to the preview feature yet. For what it's worth, neither do I.

It's possible that the ability to opt-in hasn't rolled out to every account yet (including ours), or even that it hasn't rolled out to **any** non-internal Microsoft accounts.